# SQL procedure find 4 matching fields from 5

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write an sql procedure to identify rows that match on 4 out of 5 columns. Here's an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Match](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [col1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [col2] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [col3] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [col4] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [col5] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [match] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO dbo.Match VALUES ('1','A','A','A','A','A', null)
INSERT INTO dbo.Match VALUES ('2','A','A','A','A','B', null)
INSERT INTO dbo.Match VALUES ('3','A','A','A','B','A', null)
INSERT INTO dbo.Match VALUES ('4','A','A','B','B','A', null)
INSERT INTO dbo.Match VALUES ('5','A','B','A','B','A', null)
```

so the procedure should identify that rows 1,2 and 3 have 4 identical field values and row 3 has 4  4 identical field values to row 4 and 5.

I tried joining the table to itself and then joining on 4 fields, then doing this for every combination but it doesn't quite do what I want.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for replying, I should have been a bit clearer.

I need to know that rows 1,2,3 have four field values in common (The A's and B's) and that rows 3,4,5 have four field values in common, then either update a field in that table to record this (so for example write 'group1' to a field for rows 1,2,3 and the same for rows 3,4,5 but when a row is in two groups it might be best to write to another table and add a row to record the matches)

I have full control of the schema so can do what I need to.

So I don't need to know the number of matches for each row, but record the groups if you like in which all members of the group have four fields in common.

thanks again
CM

Comment: Row 1 have 5 identical values; rows 4 and 5 have 3 identical values. Or should we also consider `match` column?

Comment: You want to match row 3 to each of the other rows and count the matched items, correct? Or do you want to match row 3 to rows 1 and 2 simultaneously and, independently, to rows 4 and 5 simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I Do not know how you want to get the Result but try this one

```
select  distinct o.*
        , (select count(*) from match m1
            where   m1.id != o.id
                    and (
                        (o.col1 = m1.col1 and o.col2 = m1.col2 and o.col3 = m1.col3 and o.col4 = m1.col4)
                        or (o.col1 = m1.col1 and o.col2 = m1.col2 and o.col3 = m1.col3 and o.col5 = m1.col5)
                        or (o.col2 = m1.col2 and o.col3 = m1.col3 and o.col4 = m1.col4 and o.col5 = m1.col5)
                        or (o.col1 = m1.col1 and o.col3 = m1.col3 and o.col4 = m1.col4 and o.col5 = m1.col5)
                        or (o.col1 = m1.col1 and o.col2 = m1.col2 and o.col4 = m1.col4 and o.col5 = m1.col5)
                    )
            ) TestMatch
from    match o
```

HOPE THIS HELP YOU OPEN SOME DOOR!
GOOG LUCK

Answer (score 0):

While is unclear what exactly you need, you probably needs [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) your columns `col1..5` to compare your values more easily:

```
;
WITH    Match   AS
(       SELECT  *
        FROM    (   VALUES
                    (1,'A','A','A','A','A', NULL),
                    (2,'A','A','A','A','B', NULL),
                    (3,'A','A','A','B','A', NULL),
                    (4,'A','A','B','B','A', NULL),
                    (5,'A','B','A','B','A', NULL)
                )   AS SampleData(ID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, match)

),      OneColumnPerRow     AS
(       SELECT      ID, ColId, ColValue, Match
        FROM        Match
        UNPIVOT     (ColValue FOR ColID IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)) as upvt

),      RepetitionsPerValue AS
(       SELECT      ID, ColValue, COUNT(*) AS IdenticalFieldValues 
        FROM        OneColumnPerRow 
        GROUP BY    ID, ColValue

),      MaxRepetitionsPerID AS
(       SELECT      ID, MAX(IdenticalFieldValues) AS MaxRepetitions
        FROM        RepetitionsPerValue
        GROUP BY    ID
)
--SELECT * FROM OneColumnPerRow
--SELECT * FROM RepetitionsPerValue
  SELECT * FROM MaxRepetitionsPerID
```

Output:

```
ID  MaxRepetitions
1   5
2   4
3   4
4   3
5   3
```

I left some commented selects at query end so you can inspect intermediary steps and compose your final solution.